# vertical mouse wheel slider

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i have used vertical slider(Mousewheel control) in my project from https://swiperjs.com/. this is working fine, but i need positions fixed while scrolling a page. as like the following sample link in section four(https://amernitech.com/dev/). pls provide any sample demo.

```
//html
  <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper mySwiper hide-tabview page" style="background:green;">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper ">
        <div class="swiper-slide ">
            <section>
                <div class="container">
                    <!-- <div style=" margin-bottom: 50px;"><h2 class="heading heading-h2 text-white" >Creators Dashboard</h2></div> -->
                    <div class="row" style="flex-wrap: nowrap;">
                        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 " style="align-self:center;">
                            <div class="shadow-number">01</div>
                            <h2 class="heading heading-h3 text-white"> Upload your work</h2>
                            <p class="heading-L mt-4" style="color: #B7B7B7;">Get started by uploading your very own creations of all types to any array of games and projects.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6  " >
                            <img class="img-fluid custom-border-radius slider-image-wd" src="{{asset('public/assets/img/upload1v1new.png')}}"alt="" style="  margin: 0 auto;display: table;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" style="flex-wrap: nowrap;">
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 " style="align-self:center;">
                    <div class="shadow-number">02</div>
                    <h2 class="heading heading-h3 text-white">Create Collections</h2>
                    <p class="heading-L mt-4" style="color: #B7B7B7;">If you want to create multiple creations for one game, we provide you with the
                        ability to create “Collections”, so you can bundle all of your work together! </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6  " >
                    <img class="img-fluid custom-border-radius mt-2 slider-image-wd" src="{{asset('public/assets/img/createmusic1.png')}}"alt=""  style=" margin: 0 auto;display: table;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row" style="flex-wrap: nowrap;">
                    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 " style="align-self:center;">
                        <div class="shadow-number">03</div>
                        <h2 class="heading heading-h3 text-white">Earn Today!</h2>
                        <p class="heading-L mt-4" style="color: #B7B7B7;">Start earning for your creations today! We provide advanced data analytics for all
                            the work product you produce. This way you have a handle on your projects from Day 1.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6" >
                        <img class="img-fluid custom-border-radius slider-image-wd" src="{{asset('public/assets/img/dashboard1n.png')}}"alt="" style="  margin: 0 auto;display: table;">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```js
 var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
        direction: "vertical",
        slidesPerView: 1,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        mousewheel: true,
   mousewheel: {
    forceToAxis: true,
    sensitivity: 1,
    releaseOnEdges: true,
},
        pagination: {
          el: ".swiper-pagination",
          clickable: true,
        },
      });
```

```css
 html,
      body {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
      }

      body {
        background: #eee;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #000;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .swiper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .swiper-slide {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        background: #fff;

        /* Center slide text vertically */
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .swiper-slide img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="cover-container d-flex h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
  <header class="masthead mb-auto">
    <div class="inner">
      <h3 class="masthead-brand">Cover</h3>
      <nav class="nav nav-masthead justify-content-center">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main role="main" class="inner cover">
    <h1 class="cover-heading">Cover your page.</h1>
    <p class="lead">Cover is a one-page template for building simple and beautiful home pages. Download, edit the text, and add your own fullscreen background photo to make it your own.</p>

    <p class="lead">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary">Learn more</a>
    </p>
  </main>
  </div>

  <div class="swiper mySwiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="card float-left p-4">
          <div class="row ">

            <div class="col-sm-7">
              <div class="card-block">
                <!--           <h4 class="card-title">Small card</h4> -->
                <h4>Card 1</h4>
                <p>Change around the content for awsomenes</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Read More</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/150?image=380" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="card float-left p-4">
          <div class="row ">

            <div class="col-sm-7">
              <div class="card-block">
                <!--           <h4 class="card-title">Small card</h4> -->
                <h4>Card 2</h4>
                <p>Change around the content for awsomenes</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Read More</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/150?image=380" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="card float-left p-4">
          <div class="row ">

            <div class="col-sm-7">
              <div class="card-block">
                <!--           <h4 class="card-title">Small card</h4> -->
                <h4>Card 3</h4>
                <p>Change around the content for awsomenes</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Read More</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/150?image=380" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="card float-left p-4">
          <div class="row ">

            <div class="col-sm-7">
              <div class="card-block">
                <!--           <h4 class="card-title">Small card</h4> -->
                <h4>Card 4</h4>
                <p>Change around the content for awsomenes</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Read More</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/150?image=380" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>
<main role="main" class="inner cover">
    <h1 class="cover-heading">Cover your page.</h1>
    <p class="lead">Cover is a one-page template for building simple and beautiful home pages. Download, edit the text, and add your own fullscreen background photo to make it your own.</p>
  </main>
```

Comment: this code working fine, but after the last section if i add few more sections vertical slider postion not fixed, its scrolling can u add few more sections and check. also when i scroll from bottom to top slider postion is not fixed. can u pls check